# Where is this statement of Bourbaki's Dieudonné from and what does it mean?

Tags: mathematics, quote

In a few places, such as [this web page](http://self.gutenberg.org/articles/eng/Nicolas_Bourbaki?View=embedded), I have read the following statement about [Jean Dieudonné](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Dieudonn%C3%A9), who was a founding member of the French "secret society" of mathematicians, [Nicolas Bourbaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki):

> Dieudonné stated the view that most workers in mathematics were doing ground-clearing work, in order that a future Riemann could find the way ahead intuitively open.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a reliably-sourced quote that can be directly attributed to Dieudonné where he expresses this sentiment? I have been unable to find such a quote. If such a quote exists, it might be in French.
2. What did Dieudonné mean by this? That is, what did he expect that a future mathematician would do that was reminiscent of Riemann's work? If a direct quote is found as in the last question, its surrounding context might shed light on this matter.

Comment: The linked page is a reproduction of pages from the book [Notable Algebraic Topologists and Their Theorems](https://archive.org/details/NotableAlgebraicTopologistsAndTheirTheorems/page/n63/mode/2up). The quoted passage is on p.61, without any citation, other places simply reproduce it verbatim. Riemann is just a stand-in for "intuitive genius", the idea is that most mathematicians do technical work so that such a genius can see deeper without being obstructed by technicalities. It might as well have been future Galois or Grothendieck.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks. Unfortunately, the author has passed away, so there is no hope of asking from where he gained this impression.

Comment: If you are interested in Dieudonné's view of mathematicians' work generally then [chapter 1 of his book Mathematics — The Music of Reason](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-35358-5_2) gives a good idea. It seems to be much more nuanced than the OP quote would suggest.